# memory management warning in Iphone

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have some doubts in objective-C programming. I have function like this.

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) newContext {
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil)
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return managedObjectContext;
}
return nil;
```

}

But when I run analyse on my project I am seeing something like this with warning

> "Object with a +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1 (owning)
>   retain count is expected"

[image: What I see after I run analyse]

Can someone point me out so as to why Xcode is giving me a warning here. What is the correct way to return any variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies not within your code but within the name of your method. In Objective C, methods whose names start with `init` or `new` are assumed by the analyser to return an object with a retain count of 1. You are returning an object with a retain count of zero, therefore your method name should not contain `new`.

Comment: Bingo.. You are right. I changed the name of the  method to some thing else and warning went away. Thanx a lot..